# CakePHP REST Put/Post not accepting data

Tags: php, json, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am attempting to write a RESTful service using CakePHP 2.3.5. So far I've successfully created the GET functions for the resource I'm working with. I can send a GET request to `example.com/areas.json` or to `example.com/areas/1.json` and it returns the data in my database.

However, I started trying to get the edit function working. I wrote a simple edit method that simply saved the incoming data from `$this->request->data`. I'm using Postman to test the functionality and sending raw JSON over PUT or POST to `example.com/areas/1.json` returns a message telling me that the data couldn't be saved. I made the method send me more information when it failed and it tells me that there is no incoming data in either `$this->request->data` or `$this->data`.

I've been searching the Internet for solutions to this or similar problems, but everything I have tried has failed so far. I've attempted disabling CSRF checks, disabling the SecurityComponent altogether, and multiple other fixes all involving the security. Changing any of those resulted in black holing the request.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what else I could try to get CakePHP to accept the JSON data into a request? I'll include my edit function below in case that helps.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $this->Area->id = $id;
    $message['request-data'] = $this->request->data;
    if ($this->Area->save($this->request->data)) {
        $message['response'] = $this->Area->findById($id);
    } else {
        $message['response'] = "Error";
    }
    $this->set(array(
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure the Content-Type of the request is application/json.

Second, CakePHP doesn't automatically decode the JSON payload; you have to do it manually.  From the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-xml-or-json-data):

```
// Get JSON encoded data submitted to a PUT/POST action
$data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I had assumed that the json_decode would be called automatically based on the manuals section on [REST](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html#accepting-input-in-other-formats). It does say "by default it will decode any incoming JSON/XML input data", but that appears to be less than true.